# Can't import name "Dispatcher" from telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am a beginner with python-telegram-bot, I have installed version the latest version 20.2.

I installed a package "python-telegram bot"  but I got an import error upon running the code

ImportError: cannot import name "Dispatcher" from telegram.ext

I delved into the python-telegram-bot package and discovered that there is no module called Dispatcher, but several online tutorials directly imported Dispatcher from telegram.ext.

In my attempt to build a bot using Telegram, I have tried several times, but I have still received a message that says it cannot import the name 'Dispatcher' from the extension telegram.ext.As far as I am concerned, this error should be solved as soon as possible and I would appreciate if you could help me with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a version >=20.0 of python-telegram-bot but your code is written for version <=13.15. Please either upgrade your code to v20 by reading the [release notes](https://telegra.ph/Release-notes-for-python-telegram-bot-v200a0-05-06) and the [transition guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0) or install a version of PTB that is compatible with your code base.
Please note that the PTB team does not provide support for versions older than v20 anymore.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest documentation suggested by @CallMeStag, you need to do some tweaking to your code lol. There's a lot of upgrade happening with the api. Here is a sample code i tried:

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Application, ContextTypes

import requests
Token = 'My Token'

application = Application.builder().token(Token).build()



async def start(update: telegram.Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")


async def help(update: telegram.Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text='''
    /start -> Welcome to tryTalk url shortener
    /help -> Send me a url you'll like to shorten and I'll reply back with a short version of your url
    /shorten -> Enter a url 
    /contact -> Contact the bot creator
    ''')


async def shorten(update: telegram.Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Enter your URL")


async def contact(update: telegram.Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text='''
    email: princeodoi39@gmail.com
    linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/in/prince-odoi/
    ''')




application.add_handler(CommandHandler('contact', contact))
application.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help))
application.add_handler(CommandHandler('shorten', shorten))
application.add_handler(CommandHandler('start',start))

application.run_polling()
application.idle()
```